# What is the difference between で出てきた and に出てきた

Tags: particle-に, particle-で

For example:

> おすすめで出てきました

and

> おすすめに出てきました

What is each particle doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おすすめ**で**出てきました means “It came up as a recommendation.” I don’t know how to grammatically explain this usage of で.

おすすめ**に**出てきました more concretely refers to a place where that thing came up, such as a list or section. It may be translated as “It came up in recommendations.”